# MySQL confusing Timezone of stored Date object

Tags: java, mysql, date

Has anyone ever seen circumstances where MySQL gets confused about which timezone applies to a java.util.Date object while storing the Date object to a table?   I'm seeing a situation where MySQL will occasionally apply a Timezone with offset=0, and then other times MySQL will apply a Timezone with offset=-12.  I've debugged the code in both circumstances, and the code reports a Timezone with offset=0 consistently.  Any ideas about what might be going on, here?  Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Please show some code. How does "MySQL apply a Timezone"?

Answer (score 1):

A `Date` object doesn't *have* a time zone. It just refers to an instant in time.

It's unclear where you're getting a time zone from at all, but if you're expecting a `Date` to have an associated time zone, you should rethink your design.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: It's global - an instant is an instant. If you imagine two peoplein different countries, making a phone call (with no latency), they would both agree on a `java.util.Date` for "the current time" even though their *local* interpretation of "now" would be different. (The representation happens to be milliseconds since the Unix epoch, so effectively in UTC, but that's just an arbitrary zero point.)

Comment: Actually, I understand and appreciate the elegance of Java's Date concept (some instant is the same instant wherever you happen to be standing on the planet).  However, my users care about the timezone because they want to see the date expressed as local (i.e. some arbitrary, third timezone) time.  So I have to perform date arithmetic once I retrieve a stored date.

Comment: @SamHeymann: And that's fine - but you shouldn't expect that to be persisted as *part of the `Date` object*, which your question seems to imply. (Actually, the Java date/time API is generally awful - Joda Time's is much better. But that's a different matter.)